# Unable to create data through Apache Isis

Tags: mysql, innodb, isis

I'm unable create entries through the Apache Isis wicket. Once I fill in the details for the required object and click OK, I receive the following error:

> Unable to save changes. Does similar data already exist, or has referenced data been deleted?: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

The database is new and contains no values in it, so the part about similar data existing is likely not the cause.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is some peculiarity of MySQL/InnoDB in conjunction with our use of JDO.  If you can create a small example repo on github, I'll take a look.

Also, can I suggest you subscribe to the [Isis users mailing list](http://isis.apache.org/support.html) and consider raising future issues there?

Thx
Dan